# I want to list civievents in a civimail

Tags: civievent, civimail

Is there some way to provide a list of events in civimail?  Or failing that generate a custom listing (just the fields I want) of my events so I can copy and paste it into civimail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by installing the [Fancy Tokens](https://civicrm.org/extensions/fancy-tokens) extension.